# Inserting Data into Multiple Tables in MVC 4.5 using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I have these models

```
public class employee
{
    public int Empid {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string fname{get;set;}
}
public class empLanguage
{
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string speaking{ get; set; }
}
public class EmpInsertion
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public List<ViewModels.Employee.empLanguage> EmpLangs { get; set; }
}
```

and i have this controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Insert(EmpInsertion empins)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Employee Emp = new Employee();
        Emp.name= empins.name;
        Emp.fname= empins.fname;
        var MaxID = (from emp in db.Employees select emp.EmployeeID).Max();
        EmpLanguage objlng = new EmpLanguage();
        objlng.EmployeeID = MaxID;
        foreach (var emplang in Emp.EmpLanguages.ToList())
        {
            empLanguage lng = new empLanguage();
            emplang.Language = lng.language;
            emplang.Speaking = lng.speaking;
            empins.EmpLangs.Add(lng);
        }
    }
}
```

I have two tables Employee(id, name, fname) Language(id, language, speaking, empid) it has one to many relationship, each employee can speak multiple language at same time. 
I want to add data in both tables from one view, how can I add to one employee multiple language

Comment: Please be specific in your question. You need help on server side or client side. Thank you

Comment: You can display the languages in check boxes and allow them to check the known languages, then pass the value to back end and save it :P

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this.

```
public Employee CreatePartnerWithUser(Employee employee, List<Language> language)
{
    using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
    {
        using (var trans = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var insertEmployee = context.Employee.Add(employee);
            context.SaveChanges();

            var insertLanguage = context.Language.AddRange(language);
            context.SaveChanges();

            trans.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If use DbContext and EF change your model like this:

```
public class employee
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string fname {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<language> language { get; set; }
}

public class language
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string languageName {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<employee> employee { get; set; }
}
```

then in DbContext class add this modelBuilder to have many to many relations

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<employee>()
            .HasMany(e => e.language)
            .WithMany(e => e.employee)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("employeeLanguage").MapLeftKey("employeeID").MapRightKey("languageID"));
```

after that, you can insert employee in a model like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Insert(employee emp, string langs)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using(DbContext db = new DbContext())
        {   
            if(langs != null)
            {
                string[] strLangs = langs.Split('-');
                foreach (var l in strLangs)
                {
                    string lan = l.Trim();
                    while (lan.Contains("  "))
                        lan.Replace("  ", " ");
                    emp.language.Add(new language
                    {
                        languageName = lan
                    });
                }
            }
            db.employee.Add(emp);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View("YourReturnPage");
        }
    }
    return View(Insert);
}
```

and in Insert.cshtml file adds this piece of code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Title" class="control-label col-md-2">Languages</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <textarea type="text" name="langs" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.langs"></textarea>
            <p class="help-block text-danger">Separate language keywords with - </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```